# Angular HttpClient, setting map type dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a method on an service to handle all backend requests. Instead of writing a whole bunch of different calls using the HttpClient, I thought I might write one single function that could connect to my backend and pass it arguments to handle different types of data.

Consider this function

```
public postRequest(token: string, url: string, body: any, headers: Object = {}) : Observable<any> {
//create new header object
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', token)
};
//add the headers if any
for(let index in headers){
  httpOptions.headers.set(index, headers[index]);
}
//connect to the backend and return the repsonse
return this.http.post( this.config.BASE_SERVER_URL + url, body , httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      return res;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

It works well except I wanted to be able to set the response type dynamically. Thus I could set the method to use one of my model types.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
map(res: "Attendee") => {}
//or
map(res: typeof(typeInput)) => {}
```

Is it possible to pas a "dynamic" type to the http map method so I can map the different responses to a model of my choice?

Comment: `map((res) => { return res; }),` seems pointless. It's not totally clear to me what you're trying to ask, but maybe you're looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)?

Comment: Thanks, generics is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can achieve this by using generic methods.

you can use this approach.

> my-own.service.ts

```
userAuthentication<T>(userName: string, password: string): Observable<T> {
    const url = `http://my-own.url`;
    const targetData = {
      'emailId': userName,
      'password': password
    };
    return this.http.post<CommonResponse<T>>(url, targetData, httpOptions).pipe(
      retry(3),
      map((data: CommonResponse<T>) => {
        if (data.status) {
          if (!data.result[0]) {
            this.showMessage('You are not authorized for login');
            return null;
          }
          return data.result[0] as T;
        }
        this.showMessage(data.message);
        return null;
      }),
      tap((userProfile: T) => {
        console.log('UserLogin ');
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<T>('unable to logged in')));
  }
```

> CommonResponse model

```
export class CommonResponse<T> {
  autherizationExpires: string;
  autherizationKey: string;
  message: string;
  result: T | T[];
  status: boolean;
}
```

So, when you call this method like **myOwnService.userAuthentication < LoginModel >(...params).subscribe(/ * your codes * /);**
It will inherited to the map as well.

let me know if I am not get your question.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Though it doesn't seem like the map method is smart enough to type cast the response data? Anyways, thank you.

Comment: @Rager use of generics and type hints doesn't cause any kind of casting or conversion - TypeScript doesn't actually exist at runtime. `as T` is just a note to `tsc`, it's not going to do anything in the user's browser.

Comment: You are right @jonsharpe, this is for escaping static returns, so you can reuse different methods.